# URL in XSL document() returning error

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XSL file that is transforming my Pictures XML file into small tiles, great! But I want to add a drop-down option at the top of the page that would allow me to select another album while on the pictures page. I am using the document() method to pull in the albums from another XML file, but an error is being returned:

"Error while parsing "http://mydomain.com/app/albums/?org=markk". No data is available for the requested resource."

...

```
<xsl:variable name="url" select="document('http://mydomain.com/app/albums/?org=markk')/albums"/>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
            <select>
                <option>Choose Album</option>
                <xsl:for-each select="$url/album">
                <option><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></option>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: You should add at least one additional information: is the link shown above working in browser? and by working I mean returning a well formed xml document with the correct contents

Comment: @Mircea: Yes, the URL I am using returns a well-formed XML doc that I have used to build other pages. What do you mean "add at least one additional information?"

Comment: I did not meant anything specific. I felt that your question did not described very well the problem. One detail I thought of and might be relevant is whether the xsl file is on the same domain as the URL you are using. If it is not, you could try the same xsl with a local URL (from the same domain) and see if it works

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @user845279 No, we've used another method for passing in the values we need.